# Add counter to the end of variables?

Tags: php

I have a php loop that includes a count using `$counter++`, within the loop I want to add the code below but echo out the counter at the end of `$Question` & `CheckboxGroup`. How can I do this?

```
$Question = $_POST["CheckboxGroup"];
```

So each time it loops through it will create something like this:

```
$Question1 = $_POST["CheckboxGroup1"];
$Question2 = $_POST["CheckboxGroup2"];
$Question3 = $_POST["CheckboxGroup3"];
$Question4 = $_POST["CheckboxGroup4"];
$Question5 = $_POST["CheckboxGroup5"];
```

Comment: im unclear, but sounds like a job for multidimensional arrays. $Question1 = $_POST["CheckboxGroup"][]

Comment: Your question is not clear can you just add your `php loop that includes a count using $counter++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use variables with indices as part of the variable name. That's what arrays are for.

```
$Question[$counter] = $_POST['CheckboxGroup'.$counter];
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it this way. Instead, make an array:

```
foreach ($_POST['CheckboxGroup'] as $cg) {
   $Question = $cg;
}
```

In your HTML markup, you can create the array values like so:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='CheckboxGroup[]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='CheckboxGroup[]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='CheckboxGroup[]' />
```

When received by PHP, they will appear as a numeric-indexed array, which you can loop over as I have above. If you want to be explicit about the array indices, you can do that as well:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='CheckboxGroup[item1]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='CheckboxGroup[item2]' />
<input type='checkbox' name='CheckboxGroup[item3]' />
```

Accessed in PHP via:

```
$_POST['CheckboxGroup]['item2']
```

Comment: better explain what's required html-side to get PHP to produce an array in _GET/_POSt...

Answer (score 2):

While you can do something like

```
$cnt = 1;
$${'Question' . $cnt} = $_POST['Checkboxgroup' . $cnt];
```

this gets extremely ugly extremely fast. You'd be better off using PHP's array support for form field names:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxgroup[]" value="..." />
```

and

```
$questions[1] = $_POST['checkboxgroup'][1];
```